# About the matrix indexing

Tags: matlab

I have a Zeros-matrix P of size (16,16); I need to replace first 4 rows in columns 1:4:end by 1, then next 4 rows in columns 2:4:end by one, and so on. 
I have done this, but I noticed that in second rows, the ones are repeated in columns 1 and 2, however what I want is to be only in columns 1:4:end.

Here is the code I made:

```
P = zeros(16,16); 
for i = 1 : 4 
    P(i:i*4,i:4:end)=1; 
end
```

Could you help to solve that issue. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shift the selected row by `(ii-1)*4`

```
P = zeros(16,16); 

for ii = 1:4 
    P([1:4]+(ii-1)*4,ii:4:end)=1; 
end
```

BTW: Avoid to use `i` as a variable since it's the matlab in-built function that return the imaginary unit.